# UITabBar disappear after popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, popviewcontroller

My app simplified view hierarchy is the following:

```
<UITabBarController>,
   | <UINavigationController>
   |    | <HomeViewController>
   | <UINavigationController>
   |    | <ChatViewController>
   | <UINavigationController>
   |    | <ProfileViewController>
```

The scenario is the following:

1. I display the a view for example ChatViewController:

[image]

2. Then I go to the HomeViewController, I can tap a cell and be pushed to a UserProfileViewController where I dismiss the tabBar by implementing `userProfileVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`
3. A "new message" remote notification arrive, when I tap it, I am redirected to ChatViewController. When I tap a notification, I have a function that reset the view hierarchy:

   ```
   fileprivate func resetViewHierarchy(_ rootTabBarViewController: ENTabBarController) {
       rootTabBarViewController.HomeNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
       rootTabBarViewController.ChatNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)  
       rootTabBarViewController.ProfileNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
   }
   ```
4. When redirected to the ChatViewController, the UITabBar has disappeared and a black view is display at the same position

[image]

I tried in every controller but without effect

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Is it because of the `userProfileVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` and have you ever encountered this issue? 
Thank you

Comment: You have to tabBar.isHidden property to false when you pop.

Comment: Yes it’s right can you answer this so I can valid it